# Is there a convenient way to receive file extension from mime-type?

Tags: java, mime-types

I'm receiving a file download from a server via an API, that does not attach the file extensions, when I download the file to the target directory.
A file "example.pdf" will be downloaded as "example". However I can ask the server for the mime type. I need to manually add the correct file extension to the downloaded file. I try to keep it as generic as possible, since the files downloaded might be of different mime types (but mostly commonly used types) such as pdf or jpegs.

I could create a mapping for a few types, but wonder if there is a convenient way to map common mime types to the correct file extension.

Comment: It's a reasonable question, but I think the answer will probably be "no." (There's also no single right answer for the question "What's the extension for type X?", so if you did find a tool for this, it would have to give you a list. `image/jpeg` has at least six... :-) )

Comment: FWIW, when I needed something along these lines, [this github repo](https://github.com/samuelneff/MimeTypeMap) was very helpful.